# How to find particular words from strings and merge variables by those words

Tags: r

Suppose I have a data "A" like:

```
Disease_name
(J189)Pneumonia, unspecified
(R51)Headache
(M4806)Spinal stenosis, lumbar region
(M512)Other specified intervertebral disc displacement
(C187)Sigmoid colon
(N201)Calculus of ureter
(C189)Colon, unspecified
(S0600)Concussion, without open intracranial wound
(C73)Malignant neoplasm of thyroid gland
(C509)Breast, unspecified
(K746)Other and unspecified cirrhosis of liver
(B181)Chronic viral hepatitis B without delta- agent
(R42)Dizziness and giddiness
```

and another dataset B is like:

```
parts         key
Chest       pneumonia
Head        headache
Abdominal   spinal
Abdominal   intervetebral
Abdominal   colon
Abdominal   ureter
Abdominal   colon
Head        concussion
Neck        thyroid
Chest       breast
Abdominal   liver
Abdominal   hepatitis
Head        giddiness
```

I want to find words of `B$key` from `A&disease_name` and merge A to B by those matched keywords in order to assign `B$parts` to `A&disease_name`.

How can I do this in R?

Comment: Means you want parts and disease name in your final output right?

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: I expect a dataset that has variables such as Disease_name, parts, key

Comment: No...please edit your question.

Comment: [And what have you tried so far?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: I am a SAS user but trying to become an R user so don't know if I am coding in the right way. I just found how to find the keywords that I want from strings.

Comment: CT_MAINSICK1$CODE_NAME <- as character (CT_MAINSICK1$CODE_NAME)

A = as.character(CT_MAINSICK$key)


CT_MAINSICK1[grepl(paste (A, collapse = "|"), CT_MAINSICK1$CODE_NAME), ]

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please read the info about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to give a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269). This will make it much easier for others to help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to SO! The question is clear enough for me. Here's a `tidyverse` solution.

First read some data:

```r
library(dplyr)

tmp <- data.table::fread(
"Disease_name
(J189)Pneumonia, unspecified
(R51)Headache
(M4806)Spinal stenosis, lumbar region
(M512)Other specified intervertebral disc displacement
(C187)Sigmoid colon
(N201)Calculus of ureter
(C189)Colon, unspecified
(S0600)Concussion, without open intracranial wound
(C73)Malignant neoplasm of thyroid gland
(C509)Breast, unspecified
(K746)Other and unspecified cirrhosis of liver
(B181)Chronic viral hepatitis B without delta- agent
(R42)Dizziness and giddiness",
sep = ""
)


tmp2 <- data.table::fread(
  "parts  key
Chest   pneumonia
Head    headache
Abdominal   spinal
Abdominal   intervertebral
Abdominal   colon
Abdominal   ureter
Abdominal   colon
Head    concussion
Neck    thyroid
Chest   breast
Abdominal   liver
Abdominal   hepatitis
Head    giddiness"
)
```

And then we do a join:

```r
result <-
  tmp %>%
  mutate(key = gsub(paste0(".*(", paste(tmp2$key, collapse = "|"), ").*"),
  "\\1",
  tolower(tmp$Disease_name))) %>%
  left_join(tmp2)
#> Joining, by = "key"
```

Resulting in:

```r
result
#>                                              Disease_name            key
#> 1                            (J189)Pneumonia, unspecified      pneumonia
#> 2                                           (R51)Headache       headache
#> 3                   (M4806)Spinal stenosis, lumbar region         spinal
#> 4  (M512)Other specified intervertebral disc displacement intervertebral
#> 5                                     (C187)Sigmoid colon          colon
#> 6                                     (C187)Sigmoid colon          colon
#> 7                                (N201)Calculus of ureter         ureter
#> 8                                (C189)Colon, unspecified          colon
#> 9                                (C189)Colon, unspecified          colon
#> 10     (S0600)Concussion, without open intracranial wound     concussion
#> 11               (C73)Malignant neoplasm of thyroid gland        thyroid
#> 12                              (C509)Breast, unspecified         breast
#> 13         (K746)Other and unspecified cirrhosis of liver          liver
#> 14   (B181)Chronic viral hepatitis B without delta- agent      hepatitis
#> 15                           (R42)Dizziness and giddiness      giddiness
#>        parts
#> 1      Chest
#> 2       Head
#> 3  Abdominal
#> 4  Abdominal
#> 5  Abdominal
#> 6  Abdominal
#> 7  Abdominal
#> 8  Abdominal
#> 9  Abdominal
#> 10      Head
#> 11      Neck
#> 12     Chest
#> 13 Abdominal
#> 14 Abdominal
#> 15      Head
```

<sup>Created on 2018-09-28 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>

Comment: I was not aware `data.table` is part of `tidyverse` package.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I tried your code but seems like %>% function requires the installation of a package. Could you let me know what package I need to install?

Comment: @RomanLuštrik Nah it's not, It's just that `data.table::fread()` is my personal preference to import data into R.

Comment: @SangwonSteveLee `install.packages("dplyr")`, dplyr is part of [tidyverse](https://www.tidyverse.org/)

Comment: Awesome! It works very well. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have two data frames `A` and `B`, you can use [`sqldf`](https://www.r-bloggers.com/make-r-speak-sql-with-sqldf/) to merge the two into a new data frame `C` like so:

```
C = sqldf("SELECT B.parts, A.Disease_name 
           FROM A, B 
           WHERE LOCATE(B.key, A.Disease_name) > 0")
```

*I don't have access to a working `R/sqldf` environment at the moment, so you might still need to adjust the SQL statement somewhat.*